# Stop google earth time-lapse from automatically scrolling down to itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-earth-engine

Is there anyway to stop google Earth's time-lapse from automatically scrolling down to itself? I have a google map like viewer with a vertically scrollable sidebar. When you click a location on the map it passes the lat/lon values into the web embedded time-lapse viewer link and automatically scrolls down on the sidebar to the time-lapse viewer, which I don't want to happen.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<section id="googleEarthEngine"></section>
```

Here is the javascript function that loads the ifile:

```
function loadGoogleEarthEngine(lat, lon)
{
    $('#googleEarthEngine').show();
    $('#googleEarthEngine').html('<iframe id="earthFrame" src="https://earthengine.google.com/iframes/timelapse_player_embed.html#v=' + lat + ',' + lon + ',9,latLng&t=3.23" frameborder="0"></iframe>');

}
```

CSS:

```
#googleEarthEngine
{
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 43vw;
    height: 30vw;
    margin: 2vh;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean *zoom*? Change the number `9` at the end of the URL (`...,9,latLng&t=3.23"`) to something lower, like 5

Comment: @chrki no I do not mean zoom. I will try to explain in greater detail. On my website I have a google maps like viewer. On a panel on the side I have a google time lapse viewer that I load from an ifile. When I click on the map, I pass in the lat/lon into the ifile's link which then zooms on that location. All of that is perfect. Here is the problem: _once that happens, the google earth time-lapse ifile forces the page to scroll down and shift the focus onto the ifile._ That is the problem. I have other things I want the focus to be on, so the ifile's forced scroll is problematic.